# How can I allow rapache/brew to securely connect to a MySQL database?

Tags: r, rmysql, rapache

I'm developing a web application using rapache and brew. Within the R code, I want to use the RMySQL package to query a MySQL database, but I am questioning the best way to access the login details for the database from within the R script.

Following [some suggestions for a similar problem with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3710511/best-way-to-connect-to-mysql-with-php-securely), one thought was to do the following in an interactive session to save the connection details to a file outside of `/var/www`:

```
con <- dbConnect(MySQL(), dbname = "mydb", user = "myuser", pass = "mypass")
save(con, file = "/home/myuser/sqlconnect.rda")
```

And then in the script run by rapache/brew, load the `.rda` file:

```
<%
load("/home/myuser/sqlconnect.rda")
query <- "MY QUERY"
result <- dbGetQuery(con, query)
%>
```

I haven't tried this approach yet. I'm not even sure that my `sqlconnect.rda` file will contain all of the information that it needs to connect.

Is there a more secure way to set up the `dbConnect()` statement?

### Update

Saving the `dbConnect()` output to a file does not work, because the connection has timed out. However, `source`ing a `.R` file from my user directory containing

```
library(RMySQL)
con <- dbConnect(MySQL(), dbname = "mydb", user = "myuser", pass = "mypass")
```

does work.

However, I don't know how secure this approach is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although I just do not see why would your suggestion boost security compared to having username/password in the R script file, you could store the parameters of your `dbConnect` function. Example:

```
con.details <- list("MySQL", dbname = "mydb", user = "myuser", pass = "mypass")
save(con.details, file='/nonpub/con.details')
```

And using those parameters in your brew files:

```
load('/nonpub/con.details')
con <- do.call(dbConnect, con.details)
```

As you are using rApache, loading `con.details` on every run just does not make any sense, I would rather put that line in `REvalOnStartup`, which could also save you this `save/load` issue :)

So I suggest to add `library(RMySQL); con.details <- list("MySQL", dbname = "mydb", user = "myuser", pass = "mypass")` to rApache startup and use that parameter list in the brew scripts.