# What are some of the safest ways to connect to a database with PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, syntax

I'm still new to PHP and MYSQL and I'm trying to learn both with modern coding techniques. All the stuff I find online seems to be outdated.

Can anybody suggest anything for me? I am also curious if the below code is outdated? If it is indeed outdated, can you suggest newer and safer methods?

```
<?php
    $connection = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
    if (!$connection) {
        die("Oops, error happened: " . mysql_error());
    }
?>
```

Comment: Try using `mysqli_*` functions or PDO (which is object-oriented handling of database connections).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3710511/best-way-to-connect-to-mysql-with-php-securely

Comment: If there isn't a lot of tutorials on pdo, is it worth it to learn "old" PHP syntax and then come into pdo?

Answer (score 11):

Use [`PDO`](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/php-database-access-are-you-doing-it-correctly/) functions.

**Database Connection Using PDO:**

```
$conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=myDatabase', $username, $password);
```

Answer (score 3):

> safest ways to connect to a database with PHP

If you are looking for the safe methods you actually need to fire proof your queries from injections. `MySQL` extension is going to be deprecated soon, it does not means its not `safe` now, its just the case that community dropped further development for the extension.

You can try both `PDO` and `mysqli` for your database queries, both are good.

Your choice should depends upon your database selection -

`PDO` supports around 12 different drivers, while `MySQLi` supports `MySQL` only.

**List of PDO drivers available**

```
CUBRID (PDO)
MS SQL Server (PDO)
Firebird/Interbase (PDO)
IBM (PDO)
Informix (PDO)
MySQL (PDO)
MS SQL Server (PDO)
Oracle (PDO)
ODBC and DB2 (PDO)
PostgreSQL (PDO)
SQLite (PDO)
4D (PDO)
```

Source - [pdo-drivers-in-php](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.drivers.php)

**API support**

`PDO` and `MySQLi` both offers **object-oriented API**, but MySQLi also offers a `procedural API`.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, your code is outdated. and mysql_connect, mysql_query etc will be deleted soon.

There are basically two options to use: (without installing 3rd party applications)

Take a look at http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

OR

use Mysqli http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php

Answer (score 2):

When accessing a database in PHP, we now have two choices: MySQLi and PDO.

To choose which one you want to use take a look [here!](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/pdo-vs-mysqli-which-should-you-use/)

And if you want to know why you shouldn't use mysql_* then take a look at [this post!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)

Comment: Nice comparison of the both methods.

Answer (score 0):

The first of all:

Yes, the line is outdated.

You can use instead `mysqli_*` functions which have very similar use as `mysql_`.

Secondly, if you know something about object-oriented programming, you can use PDO, as suggested in the other answers.

The last thing to mention is that **never ever show error message to the user**. He doesn't need to know that something went wrong, and he doesn't need to know WHAT went wrong. So never `die()` with error message.